# c# - Passing anonymous functions instead of hooking up events

Tags: c#, events, anonymous-function

I have recently discovered the use of Actions and anonymous functions and how they can be handy when working with tasks. I have done a couple of tests, passing anonymous functions into a class to work similarly to an event.

An example of what Im doing would be...

```
var myForm = new MyForm();
myForm.OnCertainEvent(output => {
    //interact with UI based on feedback.
}));
```

Then in the form itself, I would set an Action property with the Action passed into the `OnCertainEvent` method.

I think this syntax is very clean instead of declaring events, delegates, and hooking them up with the `+=` syntax.

Would this be bad practice to do? Obviously it isn't traditional, but does it have any negative effects? Essentially I'm just providing a callback.

Comment: If all you need is a callback, then yes, that's fine.

Comment: From a "possible problems" perspective, it's not really bad practice. In the end it translates back to invoking a delegate either way. The only issues I could see is some possible thread safety oversights, simplifications, or omissions that you might make, and they may bite you later. Probably not, though. On the other hand, reinventing the wheel and doing things in a non-standard fashion is typically considered bad practice. If you need an event-like feature, why not just use events?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733743(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: What you're providing here is a "single-cast" delegate. That is to say you provide a single delegate (that fits an Action) that is called when something happens. It'd be pretty useful to be able to support multiple delegates, and those are called "multi-cast" delegates. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx It'd also be pretty nice if you could have code called when a delegate is added or removed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx And that's how events were born.

Comment: Your question has nothing in common with *passing anonymous functions instead of hooking up events*. You can pass normal functions (a.k.a. method pointers) as well as hook up event with anonymous lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this be bad practice to do?

This is a very circumstantial question. It really depends on several key factors, like:

- What are you trying to do where you want to use an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate?
- Do you properly unwire your event handler for the class that actually handles the event?
- Are you directing wiring the `Action` or `Action<T>` delegate callback as the event handler?

It seems as though you are trying to assign a callback as an event handler, but the way you implemented it seems incorrect. It seems like you are trying to register your callback via a method namely `OnCertainEvent`, the flaw is that this could be called multiple times by the consumer and essentially you'd end up with the same number of executions as the number of callbacks invoked -- does that make sense?

Events are multicast, which means you can wire up an infinite number of handlers to listen as a callback on a single `event` that is fired. Here is an example of what I'm talking about, I wrote up a quick [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/evxSKG). The way this is written it is never able to unsubscribe the listeners since they are anonymous, which can lead to problems.

> Obviously it isn't traditional, but does it have any negative effects?

As long as you're aware of the consequences and you correctly clean up your code it should be fine. In a situation where you want to handle an event like this, you can do so more safely by having the constructor of your class (in your specific case a `MyForm`). Here is another [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yqCkdV) to demonstrate this.

It is totally possible and super powerful, and in my opinion now considered "traditional". The notion of creating your own `delegate` implementations is gone and has been since the introduction of generics and [lambda expressions](https://onlycsharp.wordpress.com/sharpening/lambda-expressions/). The last link was a shameless plug, I hope all of this makes sense and answers your question!

Comment: This is perfect. The first .NET Fiddle is what I had in mind. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very used pattern since lambdas in C#, but has it's advantages and inconveniences.

Inconvenience is only one "receiver" can be the target, with an event you can hook as many receivers as you want.

Advantage, is very easy to write a fire-and-forget type expression instead of hooking to the event.

If you want to explore more constructs on how to intercomunicate different classes, take a look also at the delegate pattern, not .net delegates, but interfaces which expose the possible functions called, like it's done in Java.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is totally fine to do. You want to watch yourself, I'd limit the methods passed to just a few lines though. Really, it depends on what you want to do in the method. If you're doing things that are separate abstractly from the main method it's probably better to actually make it as a stand-alone method. If it's just a simple change or update or something than I think it's more elegant to inline the code.

Do be careful using local data from outside the scope of the method though. It's legal but if you run into problems there's a good chance that's the issue.